# how to compare the ids from one table with the other table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables tb_user_answers and tb_preference_dropdown_answers which are as:

tb_preference_dropdown_answers

```
user_id  question_id  answer_id
1          1             2
1          2             1
1          3             1
1          4             1
1          5             1
1          6             0
1          7             0
1          8             1
1          9             1
```

tb_user_answers

```
user_id   question_id    answer_id
2             1             2
2             2             6
2             3             9
2             4            13
2             5            16
2             6            19
2             7            22
2             8            24
2             9            26
3             1             2
3             2             5
3             3             8
3             4            13
3             5            16
3             6            19
3             7            22
3             8            24
3             9            27
```

What I have to do is to take the record corresponding to particular user_id from tb_preference_dropdown_answers and match those with the tb_user_answers table and all the record corresponding should match. We also need to fetch those user_ids from the tb_user_answers which match the records of the preference table with the following condition including the conditions which I have used in my query but the query is not fetching the records:

```
$this->db->select('user_id');
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 1 && $dropdown['answer_id'] != 0){
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where('answer_id', $dropdown['answer_id']);
    $this->db->group_end();
  }
}
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 2 && $dropdown['answer_id'] == 1){
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where_in('answer_id',[4,6]);
    $this->db->group_end();
  }
}
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 3 && $dropdown['answer_id'] == 1){
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where_in('answer_id',[8,9,10]);
    $this->db->group_end();
  }
}
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 4 && $dropdown['answer_id'] == 1){
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where_in('answer_id',[12,13]);
    $this->db->group_end();
  }
}
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 5 && $dropdown['answer_id'] == 1){
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where_in('answer_id',[16,17]);
    $this->db->group_end();
  }
}
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 6 && $dropdown['answer_id'] == 0){
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where('answer_id',19);
    $this->db->group_end();
  }
}
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 7 && $dropdown['answer_id'] == 0){
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where('answer_id',22);
    $this->db->group_end();
  }
}
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 8 && $dropdown['answer_id'] == 1){
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where('answer_id',24);
    $this->db->group_end();
  }
}
foreach($user_preference_dropdown as $dropdown){
  if($dropdown['question_id'] == 9 && $dropdown['answer_id'] == 1){
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->where('question_id',$dropdown['question_id']);
    $this->db->where_in('answer_id',[26,27]);
    $this->db->group_end();
  }
}
$query = $this->db->get('tb_user_answers');
```

Comment: I do not understand what are you trying to do? Other thing, the two tables fields are the same, it´s that OK? or is a mistake of you?

Comment: join is your friend: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data see section $this->db->join(), also very important is to read through Jeff Atwood's: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/